# Creating a basic web services in php

Tags: php, web-services

I want to find how to create a simple web service using PHP. I am new to web service.
Is there any tutorial so I can learn it from the start.
Thanks all.

I want to host this webservice so I can use this web service in android app development I own my hosting space.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing particularly special about a web service when compared to any other kind of site. The major difference is that output is generally in a format other than HTML, these days it is usually [JSON, which has its own section in the PHP manual](http://php.net/json)

Aside from that it is just a matter of having sensible URIs, which may take sensible query strings or post data, and may require some kind of authentication (just like any other site).