# How to transfer data from php script to android and store them as variables?

Tags: php, android, mysql, google-maps

I retrieved latitude and longitude from server to php and I can display it in dialog box but i want store them as variable in android. How can i do that?

```
<?php
  $db_name = "sampledb";
  $mysql_user = "root";
  $mysql_pass = "";
  $server_name = "127.0.0.1";
  $a = mysqli_connect( $server_name, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass, $db_name );

  if( !$a )
  {
    echo"Connection error".mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  else
  {
    //echo"<h3>Successfull</h3>";
  }

  $bus = isset( $_POST["bus"] ) ? $_POST['bus'] : '';
  $sql_query = "select latitude, longitude from sample where bus like '$bus';";
  $result = mysqli_query( $a, $sql_query );

  if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 )
  {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result );
    $latitude = $row["latitude"];
    $longitude= $row["longitude"];
    echo "bus latitude" . $latitude;
    echo "bus longitude" . $longitude;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Bus cannot be tracked";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to save the values to use throughout the app?? Use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Are you want to Pass this lat & long to android Phone ? And in android Phone it will shown ??

Comment: Yes i want to use it in marker in google maps BhavinV

Comment: ohk... Google maps will be in android phone ???
so for that you have to make webservice for android phone. 
And You have to create json object using json_encode method. 
Use this link [Create a basic webservice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507726/creating-a-basic-web-services-in-php)